# How to change timer that is dependent on variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, time, dependencies

Hi I'm creating a web program that runs a timer that changes depending on a variable I created called level. The problem is when the timer reaches 0 it continues counting down. I know clearInterval would fix this however when clicking a button to increase to level 2 the timeRemaining function fails to count down despite adding time to the timer.

If you could please check out my code and point me in a direction I would really appreciate it.

```
var clock = setInterval(timeRun,1000);
var level = 1;

    if (level == 1 ){
        timer = 4000;
    }else if ( level == 2 ){
        timer = 10000;
    };

    function timeRemaining(endtime){
        var time = timer;
        var seconds = Math.floor( (time/1000) % 60 );
        var minutes = Math.floor( (time / 1000 / 60 ) % 60 );
    };

    function timerRun (){
        if ( level !==0 ){
            var time = timer;
            var time = timeRemaining(timer);
            timer-=1000;

            if (timer == 0 && level!== 0){
                console.log("Complete")
                //This continues the timer counting down past 0 infintiely Which I do not want. I want it to stop the timer at 0. Where am I going wrong?
                //When a button is clicked it will increase by a level. I know how to do that part.
            };      
        }else{
            console.log("Stopped");
            level=0;
            //This stops the timer
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you asking two times `if ( level !==0 )`? I would delete the second `level!==0` query and then I would try to change `timer == 0` to `timer === 0`.

Comment: I made these changes but it hasn't changed anything. timer === 0 produces the same result and the counter continues to count past 0.

Comment: Ok, now I see. Here a hint. Look precisely on the timeRemaining function. What do you notice?